# How to use pathlocationstrategy in angular 5 to set base href or APP_BASE_HREF?

Tags: angular5, angularjs-ng-href

Below is the code snippet:

import {
        Router
    } from "@angular/router";
    import {
        HttpClient
    } from "@angular/common/http";
    import {
        environment
    } from "../../environments/environment";
    import {
        Location,
        LocationStrategy,
        PathLocationStrategy
    } from '@angular/common';

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonServicesService {
    PathLocation: Location;
    referralCode: any = localStorage.getItem('referenceCode');

    constructor(
        location: Location,
    ) {
        this.PathLocation = location;
    }

    redirectAfterSuccessfulLogin() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("redirectUrl")) {
            let url = localStorage.getItem("redirectUrl");
            localStorage.removeItem("redirectUrl");
            this.PathLocation.prepareExternalUrl("'/'+this.referralCode"); //is this the correct way?
            console.log(this.PathLocation);
            this.router.navigate([url]);
        } else {
            this.PathLocation.prepareExternalUrl("'/'+this.referralCode");
            console.log(this.PathLocation);
            this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to navigate from one url to another after login ? 
like from 'localhost:3000/home' to 'localhost:3000/home/code' or you want to change the base url of the app ?

Comment: I want to change the base_href from localhost:3000 to  localhost:3000/23232

Answer (score -1):

you can do some thing like that :

1. Create a baseUrl function that takes code as a parameter.
2. Call that function according to the condition after login,this will
   gives you the updated URL

like this:

```
getBaseUrl = function(code){
return `localhost:3000/${code}`
}
```

now you can use it as :

```
getBaseURl(1234)
```

it returns : **"localhost:3000/1234"**

now you can add further path after this URL.

[image: Example]

**OR**

you can further use same function for both the URL like this :

```
 getBaseUrl = function(code){

    if(code == 0000) return localhost:3000
    else return `localhost:3000/${code}`

}
```

now whenever you are calling the function you have to pass **0000** for non-login condition Base Url and 4 digit code to get the after login base URL

```
getBaseURl(1234) // for login one

getBaseURl(0000) // for non-login one
```

Comment: Okay, so how is the value returned by `getBaseUrl` used?

Comment: by concatenating it with your API path in request.

Comment: I think the question has to do with the base_url that we set in `index.html` using `<base href>` & not appending anything to the API endpoints because that can be easily done with interceptors & all.

Comment: i dont think it is the case of index.html, it's simply the use of baseurl with path